# cordova.file.* (all directories) are null

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

I'm working on Ionic mobile app development.

My requirement is to create client side logger to track issues in app. I used the methods mentioned in https://github.com/pbakondy/filelogger, and I could able to create the log file in both Android and iOS.

For the first time when I open the app, it creates the log file in cordova.file.dataDirectory, when I **close and reopen the app in i*OS**, I'm trying to read the content of the file which was created using the below

```
$fileLogger.getLogfile().then(function (loggerContent) {
                    var temp =loggerContent;
                });
```

But the application says

```
{ 
"applicationDirectory":null,
"applicationStorageDirectory":null,
"dataDirectory":null,
"cacheDirectory":null,
"externalApplicationStorageDirectory":null,
"externalDataDirectory":null,
"externalCacheDirectory":null,
"externalRootDirectory":null,
"tempDirectory":null,
"syncedDataDirectory":null,
"documentsDirectory":null,
"sharedDirectory":null
}
```

So I couldn't able to find the file where i saved my logs.

Please help me resolve this issue or if you could recommend me a different method to get around this issue, that would be great!

Thanks for the answers

Comment: what code you are using actually?

Comment: Can you tell me how you solved this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a check list here and should solve your problem :

1-Be sure that the cordova-file-plugin is installed and works in your test environment.

2-Be sure that the cordova.js file is refrenced by your html and before your code usage.

3-Be sure to call your codes after device_ready state : 
 check [this](http://document.addEventListener(%22deviceready%22,%20yourCallbackFunction,%20false);)

4-Call your function after a short delay (use setTimeOut in Javascirpt)

Answer (score 2):

Ali's item 4 is very important:
I had a similiar problem on different platforms: cordova.file.dataDirectory was null.
I tracked cordova.file.dataDirectory over the lifecycle and it was first accessed by my Ionic 2 code BEFORE the device ready event was fired. 
My "mistake": I wanted to load data during the constructor(!) of a service. Seems too early.

Comment: I was doing the same thing in the service constructor. Glad I found this page.